# Как сделать так, чтобы при использовании foreach символы не переносились на след. строку?

Tags: c#, foreach

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите число для перевода в восьмиричную систему: ");
int b = (Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));                    
Console.WriteLine("Введите количество цифр в числе: ");
int g = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { };
for (int i = 0; i < g; i++)
{
    int c = b % 8;
    b /= 8;
    numbers.Add(c);                    
}
numbers.Reverse();
foreach (int i in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{i}");
}
```

Comment: Можно без `foreach` - `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", numbers));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [Console.WriteLine](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netcore-3.1) вставляет в конец перенос строки. Чтобы его не было, используйте [Console.Write](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.write?view=netcore-3.1):

```cs
Console.Write($"{i}");
```

Comment: Спасибо люди добрые, крепкого вам здоровья!!!!!

Comment: @Анатолий можете отметить ответ как решение :) Для этого нажмите на галочку слева от ответа

Answer (score 0):

```
//Console.WriteLine($"{i}");
Console.Write($"{i}");
```